# Mutable Array and Sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sprite

I'm making a "snake game" like player and I have the body moving fine so that it adds a block in the previous position each time it moves up to 4 then it removes the last one... etc. I'm adding each block to a `NSMutableArray` (each block is a sprite and I add the sprite to the array) and I was wondering how to get the position of one of the sprites in the array. I need this so I can check to see if the "head" is trying to move onto itself.

P.S. I'm using cocos2d for iPhone.

---

When I say position I mean the coordinates, not the index position in the array.

---

```
[tail insertObject:block atIndex:i];
[self addChild:[tail objectAtIndex:i]];
i +=1;
CCSprite *sect;
for (int j = 0; j >= i; j++) {
    sect = [tail objectAtIndex:j];
}
if (i > maxHealth) {   
    [self removeChild:[tail objectAtIndex:i-maxHealth-1] cleanup:YES]; 
    id object = [tail objectAtIndex:i-maxHealth-1];
    [tail removeObject:object];
}
```

When the scene is started `i` is set to 0 and the max health equals 3.

Comment: Are you asking how to put a variable into an array? or are you asking how to get the position of the sprites?

Comment: How to get the position of the sprites inside the array.

Comment: Do you already know how to get the position of the sprites? and do you know how to store an object into an array?

Comment: Yeah? `sprite.position;` and `[array insertObject:object atIndex:i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the position of a node in an array? Like

```
// Get the node from the array
CCNode *node = (CCNode*)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
// Retrieve the position
CGPoint nodePosition = node.position;
```

Comment: Not a node but a sprite, but I'm guessing I could do the same for a sprite?

Comment: I tried this out but after the sprite is removed from the array and the scene it still logs that x is equal. (I NSLog equal when one of the sprites has the same x value as the player) Any ideas why? *EDIT actually it gives me SIGABRT

Comment: How are you creating, adding and removing this sprite?

Comment: Edited main post, it has something to do with the array because it says out of bounds

Comment: This is the answer to my question even tho I still have more.

Comment: @stenger96: Yeah well, just make another question so we can take a better look at your new problem :)